# How to query related geometry (polygons) according pushpin?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, ado.net

I want to query data from an SQL table with geometry and geography, for example an objects table with the properties id, name, lat, long, and poly.

I have already implemented the query with ajax that gives the results of the city with the lat and long information. I want, at the same time, with ajax to also get the polygon property.

Here is my part of code:

```
var map = (function() {
  var bingMap = null;
  var mapElementID = "myMap";
  var key = "API_KEY";

  function addPin(coords) {
    var location = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(coords[1], coords[2]);
    var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(location);
    pushpin.setOptions({ text: coords[0] });

    bingMap.entities.push(pushpin);
  }
  function addCityPins() {
    for (var city = 0; city < grid.cpCities.length; city++) {
      addPin(grid.cpCities[city]);
    }
  }

  function createMap() {
    if (bingMap) bingMap.dispose();

    var mapOptions = {
      credentials: key,
      center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location('41.6000', '21.7000'),
      mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road,
      zoom: 9
    };
    bingMap = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(
      document.getElementById(mapElementID),
      mapOptions
    );
    bingMap.entities.clear();
    addCityPins();
  }
  return {
    createMap: createMap
  };
})();
// ]]>
</script>
```

---

```
protected void ASPGridView1_CustomJSProperties(object sender, Web.ASPGridViewClientJSPropertiesEventArgs e)
{
    String[][] cities = new String[ASPxGridView1.VisibleRowCount][];

    for (int r = 0; r < ASPxGridView1.VisibleRowCount; r++)
    {
        Object[] dr = ASPxGridView1.GetRowValues(r, "City", "Latitude", "Longitude") as Object[];
        cities[r] = dr.Select(o => (string)o).ToArray();
    }
    e.Properties["cpCities"] = cities;
}
```

Comment: has anybody had this kind of implementation with c#, javascript and sqldatasource